# hide columns by Id in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I have the asp.net application where I am having the editable grid view with the edit,Delete,Add options. this grid having as usual Template fields . I want to hide some columns. I know i can do that by using columns index. but i don't want to follow it. instead I want to hide columns by Id. this is because if in my application further I need to add more columns then there is need to change the code gain and again in the core. so I am choosing this way. Bu as i found `<asp:TemplateField />` does not contain Id attribute. so it is become impossible for me to hide `<asp:TemplateField/>` by Id. any remedy for this ?

Comment: If you want to do it on client side, you can assign id to the templatefield controls and use JS/Jquery to acheive the desired effect.

Comment: that is what I am saying, TemplateField does not contain any attribute which help us to get its uniqueness. can you tell me how could I get element TemplateField in javascript so that I can hide it?

Comment: @ Furqan: any update I am waiting ...

Answer (score 1):

You can always do it using column header text. Run a loop through columns of the grid view and compare header text of the column with the constant declared and hide the column, this way, if you are adding any number of columns before or after the column will not affect the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a div with an id inside a template field and hide that div with client code.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps just have a different grid markup for each "view" you want to show to the user, so one grid with all the columns, and another with limited columns.

I am assuming you would always be binding the same data to the grid (regardless of whether you are hiding/showing columns), so then you would just need some logic in your code to determine what "view" you want to show the user (i.e. what grid you want to bind to).

Comment: If i do so, then I need to code all required events for each grid, and my page load time will much become complex, as well as on each page load i need to fill respected grid... this is not time consuming. else it would better to hide respected columns...isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. Your grids can share the same event code. Of course I am not sure how complex your current events are, and which ones you are using (i.e. onDataBind), but you could perhaps think about using a presentation pattern like MVP to help reduce this complexity a bit. But i think in your case you probably would be better off doing this on the client side as others have suggested.